# Human time and when to datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, discord.py, date-parsing

I'm trying to build a dpy command where I can take a string such as, "`Tomorrow at 6pm do the dishes`", and get a datetime object and a string back.

I can easily turn everything into a custom converter for dpy, I just need some help parsing the string. Kinda like so (not real code example):

```py
@bot.command()
async def remind(ctx, *, when: TimeConverter):
    print(when.reason)
    print(when.datetime)
```

```
!remind 6h do the dishes
!remind two days do the dishes
```

I found a library called, [`dateparser`](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which converts human readable time to datetime, but it can't handle what I want it to. How would I do something like this?

Comment: What is "human readable time"?

Comment: Did you see that your linked `dateparser` has a `search`?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you could get your string in the format of something such as `5h`, you could just separate the indicators. This is how popular bots such as Dyno and Mee6 handle their mute timers.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

when = when.lower()
seconds = int(when[:-1]) * {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 3600, "d": 86400}[when[-1]]
time = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=seconds)
```